# Are there more Cocoa and Cocoa Touch videos which are worth looking at?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

To gain a better understanding, I think it would be great to watch every video available on the net. For me, training videos became sort of entertaining. I love them! And at the same time, it's the most productive form of "watching movies".

Unfortunately, I tend to find videos from conferences or podcasts only by accident, so maybe you have a handy list of links to great ressources which you want to share with us.

Many universities around the world publish session videos in local languages. Also, there are dozens of conferences around the world with great session videos, some of them free.

This list should compensate for all those who didn't get the chance to visit WWDC. Therefore, guys, let's create a handy list to fill the gaps for everyone!

This is community wiki, so just list them all! I'll start with:

**English**

- [360 Conferences (360iDev) Videos](http://www.360conferences.com/conference-videos)
- [Oredev with some good iPhone dev
  session videos](http://www.oredev.org/videos/secrets-of-iphone-performance-optimization)

**German**

- [Macoun 2009 with some interesting session videos, if you can speak German](http://macoun.de/?page_id=278)

*Please don't hesitate to post links to videos in other languages than English. Many of us speak more languages, so go ahead! We'll be excited!*

**Support this list!** To collect as many valuable links as possible, this list needs your help! Please link it in your profile like I did, for example. The more people see this, the greater the chance for more great links!

Comment: Is it just me or does [this link](https://360conferences.com/conference-videos) not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those looking to go a little beyond the basics in terms of iPhone development, the videos for the Advanced iPhone Development course I taught at the Madison Area Technical College [are now available on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).

I cover the iPhone OS frameworks in detail, from Core Data to OpenGL ES, and my detailed course notes (which you can view [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/index.html)) provide supplementary information and links to the sample applications I used for the course.

While focused on iPhone / iPad, the course may also prove useful to Mac developers, as many of the frameworks and topics translate directly to the Mac (Core Data, Core Animation, multithreading, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Cocoa Touch:
[iPhone Application Development (Winter 2010), Stanford (iTunes U)](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225)
don´t forget to download [the source files](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)
Have been watching these lectures for several weeks.

Answer (score 3):

WWDC sessions, are incredible, and you cannot go wrong with them. I'm not sure if the 2009 sessions are still on sale at ADC, anyhow, 2010 sessions (which are terrific) should be available soon.

Comment: And even better, WWDC 2010 videos are free for registered developers: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: Would be cool if they released any video they ever recorded, for free. Also the super old ones can still be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to lay down some money, the Mac Developer Network videos are fantastic: http://www.mac-developer-network.com/video/

Answer (score 2):

We've recorded a few [CocoaHeads Lake Forest presentations](http://vimeo.com/channels/cocoaheadslakeforest):

- GCD and Blocks: [Part one](http://vimeo.com/7552586), [part two](http://vimeo.com/7586513), [part three](http://vimeo.com/7953434), [part four](http://vimeo.com/7831379)
- [Unit testing](http://vimeo.com/2725498)
- Hunting leaks with Instruments: [Part one](http://vimeo.com/8145088), [part two](http://vimeo.com/8826744)

Answer (score 1):

[Core Data Video Tutorial from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html): Focus is on the mac, using Interface Builder and Cocoa Bindings with Core Data. Pretty old versions in use, but maybe still useful. Free.

[Objective-C for Ruby people](http://peepcode.com/products/objective-c-for-rubyists): Not entirely free, but not very expensive either

[iPhoneDevCamp](http://www.iphonedevcamp.org/satellites/): This is incredible! They have like 20+ "Satellite Conferences" around the world, and some of them offer free Session videos from recorded livestreams, in foreign languages.